# Spring + JAXB - Unmarshal XML with the same element root

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

I am using RestTemplate to call 2 different Rest APIs that return the following XML:

```
<response><user>...</user></response>
<response><client>...</client></response>
```

In my application I have 2 classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
class UserResponse {...}

@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
class ClientResponse {...}
```

I don't have control over the APIs, I can't modify the response XML.

How can I work with 2 different responses and the same Root Element?

Thanks.

Comment: As you have 2 different REST API calls, based on the called rest service probably you can unmarshal(parse) the response to corresponding class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead have one Response class which would contain a User and a Client class, which would be elements contained in the response root element instead. Something like that:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Response {
    @XmlElement(required = false)
    private User user;
    @XmlElement(required = false)
    private Client client;
}

class User {
}

class Client {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which type of response you are expecting you can leave off the `@XmlRootElement` annotations and use one of the unmarshal methods that take a `Class` parameter.

Comment: I am using the 
RestTemplate.exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables));

I am creating the RestTemplate and passing the Message Converter with the known classes to be bound.
If I set to classes to be bound with the same @XmlRootElement name the Massage Converter will always use the last one set in the list.